# How can I setup my Airflow DAG to finish previous DataFlow task before triggering next Dataflow job?

Tags: cloud, airflow, dataflow

I am Calling DataFlow jobs from Airflow in Google Cloud Composer,

```
a >> b >> c
```

a,b and c are tasks which are calling dataflow jobs.
I want to run b only after a dataflow job completes, problem is that they all are running simultaneously.

How can I wait till previous job completes?

Comment: You might want to check this [article](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/using-sensors-in-airflow/) where [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html) is implemented to determine whether the previous DAG is done.

Answer (score 1):

After placing a job you need to place a sensor that verify the job is completed.

Example:

```
   start_python_job_async = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
        task_id="start-python-job-async",
        py_file=GCS_PYTHON,
        py_options=[],
        job_name='{{task.task_id}}',
        options={
            'output': GCS_OUTPUT,
        },
        py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.25.0'],
        py_interpreter='python3',
        py_system_site_packages=False,
        location='europe-west3',
        wait_until_finished=False,
    )

    wait_for_python_job_async_done = DataflowJobStatusSensor(
        task_id="wait-for-python-job-async-done",
        job_id="{{task_instance.xcom_pull('start-python-job-async')['job_id']}}",
        expected_statuses={DataflowJobStatus.JOB_STATE_DONE},
        location='europe-west3',
    )

    start_python_job_async >> wait_for_python_job_async_done
```

You can view the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/dataflow/index.html?highlight=dataflowjobstatussensor#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.dataflow.DataflowJobStatusSensor) and the [examples](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#howto-operator-dataflowjobstatussensor) that explains further